# Selection sort algorithm. Swift.

Tags: swift, algorithm, sorting

There is a great resource for swift algorithms by Ray Wenderlich:
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club

One of the basic ones is "Selection Sort":

```
func selectionSort(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
  guard array.count > 1 else { return array }  

  var a = array                    
  for x in 0 ..< a.count - 1 {     

    var lowest = x
    for y in x + 1 ..< a.count {   
      if a[y] < a[lowest] {
        lowest = y
      }
    }

    if x != lowest {              
      swap(&a[x], &a[lowest])
    }
  }
  return a
}
```

I was trying to understand whats happening in here and was confused with `var lowest = x` step. 
I decided to write my own solution for the problem and didn't use that step :

```
func selectSortArray1(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    guard array.count > 1 else {return array}

    var subArray = array

    for x in 0..<subArray.count - 1 {

        for y in x+1..<subArray.count {

            if subArray[y] < subArray[x] {

                swap(&subArray[x], &subArray[y])
            }
        }
    }
    return subArray
}
```

Seems to work as intended.
However, I doubt myself. 
Is `var lowest = x` required for some edge cases?

Comment: Your solution is far less efficient since you do on the order of "count squared" swaps while the original does on the order of "count" swaps.

Comment: you mean it is more efficient to do the swap in the outer loop instead? Why is that?

Comment: Because you end up doing far fewer swaps - at most one per outer loop.

Comment: this answers my question.

Comment: You can test this yourself. Add a variable to keep track of each call to `swap`. Run both versions of the code on a series of test arrays and compare the results.